# UML reverse engineering tools for Eclipse or Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, reverse-engineering, maven

do you know any good reverse engineering tool that creates **UML** diagrams from **Java** code and **Hibernate** mappings across **multiple** projects, in Eclipse or Maven (not in the Javadoc)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/) creates recursively class diagramms from a source tree (navigatable) multiple projects are handled by adding muliple sources.
Db reengineering isn't that strong on large db schemas.
I doubt that Paradigm has support for hibernate mappings.

It sounds little bit like you're trying to catch up design after things get complicated ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try also [Eclipse MoDisco](http://www.eclipse.org/MoDisco/), although it has no support for Hibernate as far as I know, but it allows extensible reverse engineering and is built on top of the EMF project.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is possible just type "jpa annotation uml" into google and select one of the tool.

Standard Java without annotation is supported by almost all UML tools such RSA, MAgicDraw, eUML, Omondo etc...